# Web programming , simple but for a robotic project

Tags: javascript, html, css, arduino

Building an Arduino based robot that is controlled from a webpage. The build is Arduino UNO and an Adafruit CC3000 wifi board.

The connection side is fine! The Arduino is connected to the home modem, and my laptop is also connected to that.

The robot has an internal IP of 192.168.1.7 , and the bot moves when i goto the link from browser 192.168.1.7/forward .

However the doubt is , I want to set all the buttons on a webpage and add CSS to it, and I want to control the bot when i press buttons!

Which will be the best method that'll suit for me .

```
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "utility/debug.h"
#include "utility/socket.h"
#include <avr/wdt.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>

const int IN1=4;
const int IN2=2;
const int IN3=7;
const int IN4=8;
 char input;

// These are the interrupt and control pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3  // MUST be an interrupt pin!
// These can be any two pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10
// Use hardware SPI for the remaining pins
// On an UNO, SCK = 13, MISO = 12, and MOSI = 11


 Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS,            

 ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT,
                                     SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
 // you can change  this clock speed

#define WLAN_SSID       "aa"   // cannot be longer than 32 characters!
#define WLAN_PASS       "00"

// Security can be WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA or    

WLAN_SEC_WPA2
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2

#define LISTEN_PORT           80        


Adafruit_CC3000_Server httpServer(LISTEN_PORT);

String readString;


void setup()
{

 pinMode( IN1 ,OUTPUT);// Right Motor 1st wire
 pinMode( IN2 ,OUTPUT);// Right Motor 2nd wire
 pinMode( IN3 ,OUTPUT);// left Motor 1st wire
 pinMode( IN4 ,OUTPUT);// left Motor 2nd wire

 Serial.begin(115200);


  Serial.println(F("Hello, CC3000!\n")); 

  //Serial.print("Free RAM: "); Serial.println(getFreeRam(), DEC);



  Serial.println(F("\nInitializing..."));
  if (!cc3000.begin())
  {
    Serial.println(F("Couldn't begin()! Check your wiring?"));
    while(1);
  } 

  Serial.print(F("\nAttempting to connect to "));  

 Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);
  if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    while(1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Connected!"));

  Serial.println(F("Request DHCP"));
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(100); // ToDo: Insert a DHCP timeout!
  }  

 // Display the IP address DNS, Gateway, etc.
  while (! displayConnectionDetails()) {
    delay(1000);
  }
  // Start listening for connections
  httpServer.begin();

  Serial.println(F("Listening for connections..."));

wdt_enable(WDTO_4S);
}

void loop() {

    // Try to get a client which is connected.
  Adafruit_CC3000_ClientRef client = httpServer.available();

   if (client) 
  {
    delay(5);
    Serial.println(F("Client connected."));
    // Process this request until it completes or times out.


     // An HTTP request ends with a blank line
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;


        while (client.connected()) 
        {

            if (client.available())
            {
                char c = client.read();
                 //Serial.write(c);



            if (readString.length() < 100) {
                readString += c;
                Serial.print(c);
            }

            if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
              client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
              client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
             // client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
             client.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
                client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                client.println();
                client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>"); 

                //send the HTML stuff
                client.println(F("<html><head><title>Randi Control Panel</title><style type=\"text/css\">"));
                client.println(F("body { font-family: sans-serif }"));
              /*
                client.println("h1 { font-size: 14pt; }");
                client.println("p  { font-size: 10pt; }");
                client.println("a  { color: #2020FF; }");
                client.println("</style>");
                client.println("</head><body text=\"#A0A0A0\" bgcolor=\"#080808\">");
             */ 
                client.println(F("<h1>Randi Controls</h1><br/>"));

                client.println(F("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/forward\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go!\"></form>"));
                client.println(F("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/backward\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Reverse!\"></form>"));
               client.println("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/stop\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Stop\"></form>");

                client.println(F("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/Fleft\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Front Left\"></form>"));
                client.println(F("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/Fright\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Front Right\"></form>"));
                client.println(F("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/Bleft\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Back Left\"></form>"));
                client.println(F("<form method=\"link\" action=\"/Bright\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Back Right\"></form>"));
                client.println(F("<br/>"));
                client.println(F("</body></html>")); 
                client.println();
                break; 
            }

            if (c == '\n') {
              // You're starting a new line.
              currentLineIsBlank = true;
            }
            else if (c != '\r') {
              // You've gotten a character on the current line.
              currentLineIsBlank = false;
            }

        }
    }
    // Give the web browser time to receive the data.

     process(client);

      readString = "";
  }


  }  

 void process (Adafruit_CC3000_ClientRef client)
{       
   if(readString.length() > 0){
    if (readString.indexOf("/forward") > 0)
      {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
/*if (Serial.available()) {
    // read the most recent character
    */
 //  input = Serial.read();
    // switch based on the character
  //  switch(input){
    //  case 'F': 
        // forward
  analogWrite(IN1,0);
  analogWrite(IN2,255);
  analogWrite(IN3,255);
  analogWrite(IN4,0);
  //break;
  }
  else if (readString.indexOf("/backward") > 0)
      {
   //       case 'B':  // backwards
           // v=Serial.read();
       analogWrite(IN1,200);
       analogWrite(IN2,0);
       analogWrite(IN3,0);
       analogWrite(IN4,200);
      // break;
      }
   //   case 'S':  // stop

    else if (readString.indexOf("/stop") > 0)
      {
        analogWrite(IN1,0);
        analogWrite(IN2,0);
        analogWrite(IN3,0);
        analogWrite(IN4,0);
     //   break;
      }
     // case 'L':  // left
      else if (readString.indexOf("/left") > 0)
      {   
  analogWrite(IN1,0);
  analogWrite(IN2,150);
  analogWrite(IN3,0);
  analogWrite(IN4,200);
      }
      //  break;
     //  case 'R':  // right
   else if (readString.indexOf("/right") > 0)
      { 
  analogWrite(IN1,150);
  analogWrite(IN2,LOW);
  analogWrite(IN3,200);
  analogWrite(IN4,LOW);
      }//  break;
   //   default:    // if character not recognized then stop
       else if (readString.indexOf("/stop") > 0)
      {
         analogWrite(IN1, 0);
         analogWrite(IN3, 0);
     //    break;
     }
}}


// Tries to read the IP address and other connection details
bool displayConnectionDetails(void)
{
  uint32_t ipAddress, netmask, gateway, dhcpserv, dnsserv;

  if(!cc3000.getIPAddress(&ipAddress, &netmask, &gateway, &dhcpserv, 

  &dnsserv))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Unable to retrieve the IP Address!\r\n"));
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
     Serial.print(F("\nIP Addr: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(ipAddress);
     Serial.print(F("\nNetmask: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(netmask);
     Serial.print(F("\nGateway: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(gateway);
     Serial.print(F("\nDHCPsrv: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dhcpserv);
     Serial.print(F("\nDNSserv: ")); cc3000.printIPdotsRev(dnsserv);
     Serial.println();
     return true;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Some simple JavaScript to make AJAX requests will work fine.

Comment: Is your robot the web server?

Comment: the robot is not the server, it can't be the access point, it can only connect to it! So I am confident it is not the server , but still in a dilemma as the whole code is an upgrade of an existing code in Github

Comment: Can you edit your question and place the github repo link?

Comment: @Roma What is the GitHub page?  Im pretty sure the Ardunio is serving a simple RESTful web service.

Comment: I ve added my code! , sorry took much time to format it in here!

Comment: Since you can already call 192.168.1.7/forward in a web browser and trigger the robot to take an action it sounds like you have a RESTful API already setup. You need to expand that to allow the other actions you would like to perform at different API endpoints (examples: /backwards, /turn-right, /turn-left, etc.) as well as setup a web page that can implement those API calls via buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Shaeens Bot</title>

<script>

var URL='http://192.168.1.7/';

function command(dir)
{

var x=document.getElementById('frm');

frm.src=URL+dir;

}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="command('forward')">Forward</button>
<button onclick="command('left')">Left</button>
<button onclick="command('right')">Right</button>
<button onclick="command('stop')">Stop</button>

<iframe src="" id="frm" style="display:none;"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

This one was coded by a friend of mine! And it's working , any other better ideas? I am also planning to add an IP camera to  this one!

Answer (score 0):

Extending your friend's code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Roberto Novelo</title>

<script>

//Non jQuery AJAX Lib (0.4 kb) to avoid using an iframe and make it easier to read the server response...
function microAjax(B,A){this.bindFunction=function(E,D){return function(){return E.apply(D,[D])}};this.stateChange=function(D){if(this.request.readyState==4){this.callbackFunction(this.request.responseText)}};this.getRequest=function(){if(window.ActiveXObject){return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}else{if(window.XMLHttpRequest){return new XMLHttpRequest()}}return false};this.postBody=(arguments[2]||"");this.callbackFunction=A;this.url=B;this.request=this.getRequest();if(this.request){var C=this.request;C.onreadystatechange=this.bindFunction(this.stateChange,this);if(this.postBody!==""){C.open("POST",B,true);C.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");C.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");C.setRequestHeader("Connection","close")}else{C.open("GET",B,true)}C.send(this.postBody)}};


var URL='http://192.168.1.7/'; //Or whatever IP

function commandResponse(data)
{
    //Get a command response from the robot code.
}

function readState(data)
{
    //Polling function to read your robot's state (position, moving, etc)...
}

function readCam(data)
{
    //decode image data and show it somewhere on the html
}

function command(dir)
{
    microAjax(URL+dir, commandResponse);
}

setInterval(function()
{ 
    microAjax(URL+"currentState", readState);

}, 500);

setInterval(function()
{ 
    microAjax(URL+"cam", readCam);

}, 500);


</script>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="command('forward')">Forward</button>
<button onclick="command('left')">Left</button>
<button onclick="command('right')">Right</button>
<button onclick="command('stop')">Stop</button>

</body>

</html>
```

And in your robot code...

```
void process (Adafruit_CC3000_ClientRef client)
{       
    if(readString.length() > 0)
    {
        if (readString.indexOf("/currentState") > 0)
        {
            if(1==moving)
            {
                client.println(F("Moving")); 
            }
            //Exec remaining code...
```

Not sure about the client.println() part of the code since it says it will loop, so you have to see if the reply gets to the client. If it does not, you might have to find a way to stop the loop and reply to the client (if that does not break other request loops).

[here is the link to the micro ajax lib](https://code.google.com/p/microajax/)